# why JL command doesn't work in my Assembly code?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-registers, att

In my assembly program I am interested to know what's the minimal value %rsp gets (as it grows down) compared to its initial value so I wrote in main:

```
mov %rsp, %rcx #start
mov %rsp, %rdx #max
```

and in every part in my code before push (or any other command that may affect %rsp) I wrote:

```
cmp %rsp, %rdx
jl next3 # current rsp is less that prev_max then skip the update of value for max
mov %rsp, %rdx
next3: # every time this is copied I change the number like next4, next5 etc...
```

but when I debug my code rdx and rcx share the same value, why is that?

Comment: Stack grows down and at&t uses reverse operand order. You either want `cmp %rdx, %rsp` or swap the `jl` for `jg` (or `ja` as you really should be using unsigned).

Comment: @Jester tried ja too, same problem you can try it on: https://onlinegdb.com/5CKsK1GNT

Comment: Note that `jg` or `ja` over a `mov` instruction would be simpler to understand as `cmovna %rsp, %rdx`, or `cmovb %rsp, %rdx`

Comment: Umm actually my mistake, you do have `jl` to **skip** the block so that should have worked. In fact if I change line 60 in your link to `jl` and then examine `rcx` and `rdx` at line 186 they do differ as expected.

Comment: so what's the problem, I am confused once you tell me to use jl and once ja...

Comment: There is no problem, if I use `jl` it works as expected. Sorry about the confusion, I assumed you got the condition reversed since you said it did not work.

Comment: why jl (jump less)? when rsp is less than then I want to save it not to ignore the saving...

Comment: Yes, `jb` is recommended as it's unsigned but `jl` works just as well in the general case as the stack is in the positive half in x86-64. at&t still uses reversed order so after `cmp %rsp, %rdx` `jl` jumps if `rdx < rsp` which is what you want because that means `rdx` is already lower so you want to skip the assignment given that stack grows down.

Comment: it returns wrong value (16) even though I know the stack goes beyond 20

Comment: You put a stack check block in between a compare and a conditional jump from line 73, so your code goes to `finish` and indeed only uses 16 bytes.

Comment: you were wrong, first of all jl means jump if lower in att and given cmp %rsp, %rdx it means jump if the first which is rsp is lower than rdx not the opposite. Plus, I made manual check and the answer is 0x40 not 0x16. @Jester

Comment: I have been known to be wrong :) But no, in at&t is the opposite. And I have run your code on the online gdb and since you put that block in the wrong place it returns early as I said, so that's why it gives 16 (0x10 not 0x16 ... talk about being wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stack checking code is in fact correct. Since you provided full code[*] we can see there is a problem starting from line 73:

```
    cmp (%rdi), %esi
    
    cmp %rsp, %rdx
    jl next4
    mov %rsp, %rdx
    next4:
    
    jne continue
```

Your stack check is in between the `cmp (%rdi), %esi` and the `jne continue` so it will use the flags from `cmp %rsp, %rdx` instead. As it happens those are equal at that point so your function will not go to `continue` but return. The stack space used will just be 16 bytes. Note this stack check block is useless as the stack pointer can not change from the previous one so you can remove lines 74-80. This will then produce a stack usage of 0x40 bytes as you expect.

As to the question of operand order, at&t uses the reverse to intel. Consider this code:

```
mov $1, %eax
mov $2, %edx
cmp %eax, %edx
jl next
```

This will **not** jump.

---

[*] https://onlinegdb.com/5CKsK1GNT with `ja` changed back to `jl`